# 2 ISPs - use 1 for browsing surfing and other for torrents

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I have 2 ISPs:

a) ISP1 - has a 500 mbps line but blocks torrents (when i say block, its a packet level thing so no way around it. VPNs also don't work and i don't wanna invest)

b) ISP2 - supports torrenting but has 10 mbps line

can i use both of them together in such a way that i do everything via ISP1 but use ISP2 only for my torrents (utorrent access). can i do such a setup if its possible?

thanks!

Comment: What are you using for a dual wan router? This is most definitely possible...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make a VPN work for torrenting, so that you can use your full speeds.

It is also possible to use ISP2 only for torrenting, however the optimal answer would depend on how your dual WAN network is set up.

uTorrent has a setting where you can specify the outgoing ip in [settings->advanced] (net.outgoing_ip) however, depending on how your network is, this may not be a viable solution.